# How to solve this equation for $z(x)$?

Tags: calculus, homogeneous-equation

$xdy = (y - \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}) dx$

$y(x) = z(x) x$

$dy = zdx+xdz$

$x(zdx+xdz)=(zx-\sqrt{x^2 +x^2 z^2}) dx$

$x(zdx+xdz) =x(z-\sqrt{1+z^2})dx$

$(zdx+xdz)=(z-\sqrt{1+z^2})dx$

Comment: Simplify the $z\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that on the RHS, when you multiply the dx term with the ones in the bracket, the term zdx appears, which is also present in the LHS. Therefore they both cancel out, and now you are left with a simpler equation. Just rearrange them afterward, and the solution becomes easy.

- dx/x = dz/√(1+ z^2)
- ln(x) = ln( z + √(1+ z^2))
  1/x = z + √( 1+ z^2)[image]

Comment: I got $xdz=-dx \sqrt{1+z^2} $. How can I solve it for z?

Comment: I hope the edit helps. I still have to learn how to use mathjax, so if it doesn't make sense, I'll send you an attachment.

Comment: Could you please send me the attachment?

Comment: I have sent you one. Tell me if this helps.

Comment: Ok, so after that I need to solve the int of $ \frac {dz} {\sqrt{1+z^2} } $ right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. And that is what I have done in the attachment as well

Comment: What's general solution for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106478/discussion-between-srinath-prasad-and-leana-k).